# How to search with django_tables2 when using filters

Tags: filter, filtering, django-tables2

My problem is that I can not take back any data after filtering.
My search fields are : id name and surname. The two last taken from the Client which is foreign key.

filters.py

```
class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    client__name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    client__surname = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id']
```

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,verbose_name=u'Client')
```

tables.py

```
class OrderTable(tables.Table):

    #CUSTOM COLUMN EXAMPLE
    order_id=tables.Column(verbose_name= 'ID Order',orderable=False,empty_values=())

class Meta:
        #define the model
        model = Order
        exclude=('id')
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
        sequence = ("order_id")
```

views.py

```
class OrderListView(SingleTableMixin,FilterView):
    table_class = OrderTable
    model = Order
    template_name='orders/orde_list.html'
    filterset_class = OrderFilter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrderListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ##filter the orders of the past 4 months.
        last_four_months=date.today() - timedelta(120)
        object_list=Order.objects.filter(order_created__gte=last_four_months,ays=1).order_by('-invoice_date')
        table=self.table_class(object_list)
        RequestConfig(self.request).configure(table)
        context['table'] = table
        #clear all fields
        has_filter = any(field in self.request.GET for field in set(self.filterset_class.get_fields()))
        context['has_filter'] = has_filter
        return context
```

I noticed that when I create a custom queryset to fill my table, for ex: object_list=Order.objects.filter(order_created__gte=last_four_months).order_by('-invoice_date')  the filtering is not working.

When I put nothing it works properly.

Any idea why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I have not defined that my custom queryset must be inserted in the custom table(tables.py) and more important to be filtered by the custom filter (filters.py).

After doing that the custom queryset filtered correctly.

```
class OrderAYSListView(LoginRequiredMixin,SingleTableMixin,FilterView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    table_class = OrderTable2
    model = Order
    template_name='orders/order_ays_list.html'
    filterset_class = OrderFilter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrderAYSListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ##filter the orders of the past 4 months.
        last_four_months=date.today() - timedelta(120)
        object_list=Order.objects.filter(order_created__gte=last_four_months,ays=1).order_by('-invoice_date')

        f = self.filterset_class(self.request.GET, queryset=object_list)
        context['filter'] = f
        table = self.table_class(f.qs)
        RequestConfig(self.request).configure(table)
        context['table'] = table
        #clear all fields
        has_filter = any(field in self.request.GET for field in set(self.filterset_class.get_fields()))
        context['has_filter'] = has_filter
        return context
```